# Discord javascript problem for my bot Cannot read property

Tags: discord.js

Please help me.

C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\matthe-guard\jahky.js:428
newChannel.cache.roles.cache.forEach(async function (jahky) {
^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined
at Client. (C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\matthe-guard\jahky.js:428:22)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

```
client1.on("channelUpdate", async (oldChannel, newChannel) => {
    let entry = await newChannel.guild.fetchAuditLogs({ type: 'CHANNEL_UPDATE' }).then(audit => audit.entries.first());
    if (!entry || !entry.executor || Date.now() - entry.createdTimestamp > 10000 || !newChannel.guild.channels.cache.has(newChannel.id)) return;
    if (matthe1.bots.includes(entry.executor.id)) return;
    if (matthe1.owners.includes(entry.executor.id)) return;
    if (matthe1.guvenlid.includes(entry.executor.id)) return;
    if (newChannel.type !== "category" && newChannel.parentID !== oldChannel.parentID) newChannel.setParent(oldChannel.parentID);
    if (newChannel.type === "category") {
        newChannel.edit({ name: oldChannel.name, });
    } else if (newChannel.type === "text") {
        newChannel.edit({ name: oldChannel.name, topic: oldChannel.topic, nsfw: oldChannel.nsfw, rateLimitPerUser: oldChannel.rateLimitPerUser });
    } else if (newChannel.type === "voice") { newChannel.edit({ name: oldChannel.name, bitrate: oldChannel.bitrate, userLimit: oldChannel.userLimit, }); };
    oldChannel.permissionOverwrites.forEach(perm => {
        let thisPermOverwrites = {}; perm.allow.toArray().forEach(p => { thisPermOverwrites[p] = true; }); perm.deny.toArray().forEach(p => { thisPermOverwrites[p] = false; });
        newChannel.createOverwrite(perm.id, thisPermOverwrites);
    });
    newChannel.cache.roles.cache.forEach(async function (jahky) {
        if (jahky.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR") || jahky.permissions.has("BAN_MEMBERS") || jahky.permissions.has("MANAGE_GUILD") || jahky.permissions.has("KICK_MEMBERS") || jahky.permissions.has("MANAGE_ROLES") || jahky.permissions.has("MANAGE_CHANNELS")) {
            jahky.setPermissions(0).catch(err => { });
        }
    });
    newChannel.members.ban(member.id, { reason: `İzinsiz Kanal Güncellemek!` });
    let channel = client1.channels.cache.get(ayarlar1.log2)
    if (!channel) return console.log('Kanal Günceleme Koruma Logu Yok!');
    const jahky = new Discord1.MessageEmbed()
        .setTimestamp()
        .setColor(ayarlar1.color)
        .setFooter(ayarlar1.footer)
        .setDescription(`
**İzinsiz Kanal Güncellendi!**

**Yetkili Bilgisi**
**${entry.executor.tag}** **||** **${entry.executor.id}**

**Kanal Bilgisi**
**${oldChannel.name}** **||** **${oldChannel.id}**

**Yetkili sunucudan yasaklandı! Rollerdeki tüm yetkiler kapatıldı.**`)
    channel.send({ embed: jahky })
    return client1.users.cache.get(ayarlar1.sahip).send(`**Sunucuda kanal güncellendi! Güncelliyen kişinin bilgileri :** \n**Kullanıcı Adı :** \`\`${entry.executor.tag}\` **Kullanıcı idsi :** \`${entry.executor.id}\`\`\n**Kanal İdsi :** \`\`${oldChannel.name}\`\` **Kanal İdsi :** \`\`${oldChannel.id}\`\``)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`GuildChannel#cache` does not exist. You can simply remove it and continue with your property chain.

```js
newChannel.roles.cache.forEach(...)
//        ^ no cache
```